# How to get the "List of constraint violations" while validating JSON input from the client?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

I am working on the client side validation and have implemented some of the validations on the POJO class.
Now, when I am entering the data intentionally I am getting an exception in the below format:

> List of constraint violations:[
>     ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must be greater than or
>   equal to 900000000', propertyPath=phoneNumber, rootBeanClass=class
>   com.org.infy.prime.RestWithJPA.CarrierFile,
>   messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.Min.message}'}
>     ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='length must be between 1
>   and 20', propertyPath=accountID, rootBeanClass=class
>   com.org.infy.prime.RestWithJPA.CarrierFile,
>   messageTemplate='{org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length.message}'}
>   ]

Can anyone help me out regarding how I can get a hold of this list to generate the customized report?

Comment: How do you *"enter"* the data? By making a request that is handled by a controller or what?

Comment: yes the request is handled by the controller.

Comment: Then you could use the Errors class. Check example 6 from this guide: https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/org.springframework.validation.Errors

Comment: Thanks for you help!!! but its kind of manual process as i have already implemented validation on the POJO class using annotations,all that left is to get hold of the list ...

Comment: What do you wan't to do with the list, I don't get it? You would like to persist the errors into DB for statistics or return an altered message?

Comment: Also you could check some of the extraordinary uses of Errors by a search strategy like: https://www.google.com/search?ei=8YmOW677N4GssgHIu5yABw&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+Errors+errors+&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com+Errors+errors+&gs_l=psy-ab.3...11412.42091.0.42555.28.26.2.0.0.0.156.2018.21j4.25.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.1.114...0j0i22i30k1.0.dMTB6ZHX5tU

Comment: And then how do JHipster takes care about building errorDTO message and description from the Errors class. https://github.com/jgasmi/jhipster/blob/28c809b3bdb1dabfa409c3f69c59914ca94c3904/src/main/java/com/mycompany/app/web/rest/errors/ExceptionTranslator.java#L30

Comment: ok ,See i have around 500 fields on which i have to perform validations ..so checking each and every field manually is the tedious task so for that i have implemented the annotations ...additionally i have to create the report based on all the errors

Comment: You could receive an answer only if you specify the task more appropriate and some basic code (down stripped or so)...